# Capture any Change in the form - React

Tags: reactjs

I have Form with at least 30 inputs.
I want to show a message `Do you want to save the changes ?`  only if there is any change is made by the user, else don't show that message.
The solution i can think of is,

1. Add `onChange` event in every input field .
2. create a boolean `state` variable like `isChanged` and initialize with `false` .
3. On any `onChange` event trigger , call a method like `handleChange` .inside `handleChange` method , set the value of `isChanged` variable to `True`.
4. If `True` then show the message else dont.

My Question is, is there any way we can capture onChange from a Form level instead of captureing `onChange` from individual fields ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My Question is, is there any way we can capture onChange from a Form
> level instead of captureing `onChange` from individual fields?

Yes, you can use a `form` element's `onChange` event handler.

You can add an additional chunk of state to track if the form is dirty or not, and in some callback you where you want to display the message/warning check the `dirty` state and conditionally display the message.

```
const [dirty, setDirty] = React.useState(false);

const markFormDirty = () => setDirty(true);

...

/* in some callback */
if (dirty) {
  ... logic to trigger message ... 
}

...

<form onChange={markFormDirty}>
  ...
</form>
```

```js
function App() {
  const [formKey, setFormKey] = React.useState(0);
  const [dirty, setDirty] = React.useState(false);

  const markFormDirty = () => setDirty(true);

  const resetState = () => {
    setFormKey((key) => key + 1);
    setDirty(false);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    resetState();
  };

  const resetHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (dirty) {
      if (window.confirm("Do you want to save the changes?")) {
        window.alert("Saved!");
        resetState();
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        Form key: {formKey} - isDirty?: {dirty ? "yes" : "no"}
      </h1>
      <form
        key={formKey}
        onChange={markFormDirty}
        onSubmit={submitHandler}
        onReset={resetHandler}
      >
        {Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i).map((i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <label>
              Text {i + 1}
              <input id={`test-${i}`} type="text" />
            </label>
          </div>
        ))}

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```